# How can I completely delete a page from the portal?

Tags: websphere-portal

I'm kinda new to Websphere Portal. I'm trying to completely delete a page because I need to re-use the "unique name" I gave to it when I created this page, but when trying to edit this page the Edit Icon doesn't appear:
[image]

"acssp.home" is the unique name I'm trying to re-use.

Comment: If you want delete page go to Manage Pages -> Locate your page -> press Delete

Comment: That's what I did, but the unique name reference is still in somewhere, and I need it because the application uses it in a lot of places, I don't want to replace that on my local env.

Answer (score 0):

You can use xmlaccess script to delete a portal page. You can find the same at location IBM\WebSphere\PortalServer\doc\xml-samples\DeletePage.xml on server.

In this file replace "ibm.portal.SamplePage" with unique name of your page and then import this xml using 'import xml' option on administration page.

Here is the content of the above file:

```
<portal action="locate">

    <content-node action="delete" uniquename="ibm.portal.SamplePage">
    </content-node>

</portal>
```

Comment: Hi, I ran the xml script successfully, but this message appeared:
"The resource could not be found for deletion, possibly because it was already deleted".
However, when I try to reuse the same unique name (acssp.home), the following error appears:
"EJPAX0008E: The custom name was not changed because it is not unique"

Answer (score 0):

Try using the xmlaccess script from the following path to run a cleanup task:

IBM\WebSphere\PortalServer\doc\xml-samples\Task.xml